# is it possible to create an if statement dynamically using list elements and OR?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I'm trying to adapt the code I wrote below to work with a dynamic list of required values rather than with a string, as it works at present:

```
required_word = "duck"
sentences = [["the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jump", "over", "lazy", "dog"],
            ["Hello", "duck"]]

sentences_not_containing_required_words = []

for sentence in sentences:
   if required_word not in sentence:
      sentences_not_containing_required_words.append(sentence)

      print sentences_not_containing_required_words
```

Say for example I had two required words (only one of which are actually required), I could do this:

```
required_words = ["dog", "fox"]
sentences = [["the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jump", "over", "lazy", "dog"],
            ["Hello", "duck"]]

sentences_not_containing_required_words = []

for sentence in sentences:
   if (required_words[0] not in sentence) or (required_words[1]not in sentence):
      sentences_not_containing_required_words.append(sentence)

      print sentences_not_containing_required_words
      >>> [['Hello', 'duck']]
```

However, what I need is for someone to steer me in the direction of a method of dealing with a list that will vary in size (number of items), and satisfy the if statement if any of the list's items are not in the list named 'sentence'. However, being quite new to Python, I'm stumped, and don't know how to better phrase the question. Do I need to come up with a different approach?

Thanks in advance!

(Note that the real code will do something more complicated than printing sentences_not_containing_required_words.)

Comment: You probably want the `any` function.  `any(w in sentences for w in words)`.

Comment: You could also use set intersection: `len(set(required_words).intersection(sentence)) > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct this list pretty easily with a combination of a list comprehension and the [any()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) built-in function:

```
non_matches = [s for s in sentences if not any(w in s for w in required_words)]
```

This will iterate over the list `sentences` while constructing a new list, and only include sentences where none of the words from `required_words` are present.

If you are going to end up with longer lists of sentences, you may consider using a generator expression instead to minimize memory footprint:

```
non_matches = (s for s in sentences if not any(w in s for w in required_words))

for s in non_matches:
    # do stuff
```